# REST API for linked in is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, linkedin-api

here i have created a function to share on linkedin. In this function ajax request will preform the action to share it. As mentioned in API documentation data and URL have been given properly. Still it is not working.

```
 function share() {

            var share_data = '{  "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",  "content": {    "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",    "description": "Leverage LinkedIns APIs to maximize engagement",    "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",   "submitted-image-url":"https://example.com/logo.png"  },  "visibility": {    "code": "anyone"  }  }';
            share_data=JSON.parse(share_data);

            console.log(share_data);

                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    data: share_data,
                    headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    },
                    crossDomain: true,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json',
                    success: function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("error"+xhr);
                    console.log("error"+status);
                    console.log("error"+errorThrown);
                    }

                });


            }
```

it is showing `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error in browser console. I am running this program in a server.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `dataType` parameter to `dataType:"jsonp"`

Comment: I don't think that resolve, Linkedin doesn't allow you to use that kind of API client side. You only get an object with this inside `comment: "Check out developer.linkedin.com!"`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't on server side you are on client side (browser) and that kind of API doesn't support cross domain requests.

As LinkedIn said you have to use their [Javascript SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk) to use their API client side.

So possibilities are:

1. You use the API you are using server side (PHP, Ruby, Node.js, ASP, ecc...)
2. You use their SDK to run the API in client side